# Resolving dependency in Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I copied a repository pattern sample which uses AutoFac as IOC, But in my project i use UNITY, Any idea on how to write this in Unity 3.0

AutoFac:

```
  builder.Register<IUserRepository>(x => new UserEntityRepository (x.Resolve<IDataContextFactory<SampleDataContext>>())).SingleInstance();
```

Class where IOC will be injected:

```
public class UserEntityRepository : EntityRepository<User, SampleDataContext>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserEntityRepository(IDataContextFactory<SampleDataContext> databaseFactory)
        : base(databaseFactory)
    {  }
}
```

Comment: Are you open for configuration based solution or just code based?

Comment: I'm looking for code based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked as i expected.., (based on Wiktor's solution)

```
        container.RegisterType<IUserRepository>                
           (new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
           new InjectionFactory(c => new UserEntityRepository 
              (new DefaultDataContextFactory<SampleDataContext>())));
```

Answer (score 1):

Unity would resolve the constructor parameter automatically, if the dependency is registered. The simplest version would be then

```
container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserEntityRepository>( 
   new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() );
```

However, what you do is slightly more complicated as it gives you more freedom in selecting specific parameter values. In Unity you can have this with the injection factory:

```
container.RegisterType<IUserRepository>( 
    new InjectionFactory(
       c => new UserEntityRepository( 
         c.Resolve<IDataContextFactory<SampleDataContext>> ), 
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() );
```

This pretty much seems like your autofac version. Remember to register the data context factory first.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, the injectionFactory helped. I have tweaked the code a bit in my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserEntityRepository>();
```